# Append to YAML list - how do I only 'append' the value?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have been googling for about the last hour and haven't found a solution yet. I'm trying to generate a `.yaml` file which should have the following format:

```
"objects":
   -"dog"
   -"cat"
   -"rabbit"
```

The file is initially empty (only `objects` should be there) and the names should get appended. this is how it looks at first:

```
"objects":
```

trying to append to an empty list gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\others\py_projects\learn\controller\addNewItemController.py", line 67, in onSave
    cur_yaml["objects"].append(self._model.myObjectName)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

My code below:

```
objectNameDict = [self._model.myObjectName]
        with open('files/object.yaml', 'r') as yamlfile:
            cur_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile)
            cur_yaml = {} if cur_yaml is None else cur_yaml
            cur_yaml["objects"].append(objectNameDict)
            print(cur_yaml)

        with open('files/object.yaml', 'w') as yamlfile:
            yaml.safe_dump(cur_yaml, yamlfile, explicit_start=True, allow_unicode=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

figured out the list issue (thanks to lasrks), but the first try always fails because the list is empty.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to `append` a list to another list.  Forget YAML for a moment and think about Python. If I start with a list...

```
>>> mylist = ['thing1']
```

...and then try to `append` a list to it, I end up with a nested list:

```
>>> mylist.append(['another', 'list'])
>>> mylist
['thing1', ['another', 'list']]
```

That's exactly what you're seeing in your question. If you want to add the items in the poorly named `objectNameDict` to an existing list, you want the `extend` method:

```
>>> mylist = ['thing1']
>>> mylist.extend(['another', 'list'])
>>> mylist
['thing1', 'another', 'list']
```

---

When you read in your initial YAML file, in which the `objects` key exists but is empty:

```
---
objects:
```

You end up with a data structure that looks like this:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> with open('file.yml') as yamlfile:
...   cur_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile)
...
>>> cur_yaml
{'objects': None}
>>>
```

In order to turn that into a list, you'll want to do something like:

```
>>> if cur_yaml['objects'] is None:
...   cur_yaml['objects'] = []
```

Comment: yes, figured that out just now. currently, the problem is with the 'initially empty' list. this works when there's at least one value, but I can't have that. this is actually a reference to the folders I am renaming and until anything gets renamed, this list should be empty. how do I make it work with an 'empty first' list?

Comment: What exactly does the YAML file look like when the list is "empty"? Does it have the `objects` key or not? If it does, what is the value? (Probably best to update your *question* with this information, where you can format it properly, rather than leaving it as a comment.)

Comment: edited the question with traceback. yes, the "objects" key exists.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: it works! thank you so much. I couldn't understand why it was turning into Nonetype so thanks for the explanation!